# Node.js returns nothing when executing a js file

Tags: node.js

I want to create a Discord bot and wrote the first lines of code. When I want to execute the code with node, it returns nothing. Here is my code in the file bot.js:

`console.log("Testing...");`

It's just one line of code and when I run node bot.js it returns a blank space.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get `>` if you run `node` only?

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: I figured it out, I had to run CMD as an administrator